# Base64 Decoding, output is not correct using UTF-8, UTF-16

Tags: java, mysql, spring, utf-8, base64

i've built local restAPI server on my computer, and i have register function, sending user data to mySQL database.

I've encoded the Password String to base64 String (Wanted to try to encrypt my self).
When i try to Decode the Password i fetch from the DB, i get wrong output.

Password for example (base64): MDQ1MTA0NTE=

Which will output- 04510451

The decoder class -

```
byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);  


return new String(decodedValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The encoder class -

```
byte[] passEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("encoded value is " + new String(passEncoded));
String finalPass = null;
finalPass = new String(passEncoded, "UTF-8");

return finalPass;
```

Now the actual output i get : "ӎuӎu" (needs to be 04510451)

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's possible that your input `password` is not UTF-8

Comment: @ernest_k Look at encoder class, finalPass = new String(passEncoded, "UTF-8");

Comment: I'm referring to this: `Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));`. If the text in `password` is not UTF-8, then the result is not what you expect.

Comment: @ernest_k -@GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
 public -@ResponseBody String addNewUser (-@RequestParam String email -@RequestParam String password, -@RequestParam String phone)   This is the register function, email is String, password is String, i dont know what do .....

Comment: `new String(passEncoded)` is not the same as `new String(passEncoded, "UTF-8")`.  Remove that println statement, and instead print out `finalPass`.

Comment: It looks like you are decoding twice: `MDQ1MTA0NTE=` -> `04510451` -> `ӎuӎu`

Comment: @yonatanhornstein its hard to understand, why you need to decode, ideally passwords are stored as encoded and while validating the password for login, the password supplied by user is encoded again and only encoded `strings` are matched, not the actual `password`. If you want I could explain in detail.

Comment: That's not even a mildly secure way to handle passwords.

Comment: @ernest_k String uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set. Both UTF-16 and UTF-8 cover the entire character set so the point you raised is not a problem.

Comment: @TomBlodget did you notice this: `Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are decoding twice. This is not visible in the code snippets you provided but would be the most logical explanation:

`MDQ1MTA0NTE=` -> `04510451` -> `ӎuӎu`